# Is there a way to use a specified range as variables for SQL select statement?

Tags: sql, arrays, excel, vba, variables

I am working using SQL in Excel VBA. I am trying to exclude a large number (24) of variables from one of the columns. I tried to put all the variables as an array then have the array as the singular variable to put into the statement, but it did not work.

*[Library References](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7x6r5.png)

This is what I tried when testing to see if you could use an array in the statement. But I would prefer to reference a range that lists the 24 JTs.

```
Dim array1 As Variant
array1 = Array("CO", "DE", "TD", "SF")

strSQL = "SELECT * " & _
     "FROM [Roster$] " & _
     "WHERE [10] IN(SELECT MAX([10])" & _
                    "FROM [Roster$] " & _
                    "GROUP BY [1] ) " & _
     "AND [4] NOT LIKE """ & "%" & array1 & "%" & """ "
```

Attached below is the entire subroutine. Sorry if the format sucks, I am still learning VBA and SQL.

```
Option Explicit
Sub ActiveJT()

Dim strFile, strCON, strSQL
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim LastRow2 As Long

'JT that aren't active
Dim JT1 As String
JT1 = "CO"

Dim JT2 As String
JT2 = "DE"

Dim JT3 As String
JT3 = "TD"

Dim JT4
JT4 = "SF"


Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

strFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
strCON = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
& ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cn.Open strCON

'**********THIS IS WHERE I NEED THE HELP****************
'In the last line of the statement, is there a way to 
'have JT4 be a range on a sheet that lists 24 other JTs
'and have them all in an array or something? Or do I 
'have to make and an additional "AND" line for each
'variable I want to exclude?
'*******************************************************
strSQL = "SELECT * " & _
     "FROM [Roster$] " & _
     "WHERE [10] IN(SELECT MAX([10])" & _
                    "FROM [Roster$] " & _
                    "GROUP BY [1] ) " & _
     "AND [4] <> ""CO"" " & _
     "AND [4] NOT LIKE """ & "%" & JT4 & "%" & """ "



rs.Open strSQL, cn

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Dim r As Integer
r = 2
Dim c As Integer
c = 1

Cells(r, c).CopyFromRecordset rs
rs.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: You can't use an array like that - in SQL you'd have to write `... AND ( [4] NOT LIKE '%CO%' AND [4] NOT LIKE '%DE%' AND ...)` etc.  You could loop over the array and build that part of the SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the last part from an array (which you could read from a range):

```vb
    Dim strSQL, arrExclude, i As Long, sqlEx As String, sep As String
    
    'JT that aren't active
    arrExclude = Range("inactiveJT").Value 'read array from range
    
    strSQL = "SELECT * " & vbLf & _
         "FROM [Roster$] " & vbLf & _
         "WHERE [10] IN(SELECT MAX([10])" & vbLf & _
                        "FROM [Roster$] " & vbLf & _
                        "GROUP BY [1] ) " & vbLf & _
         "AND [4] <> ""CO"" " & vbLf
         
     sqlEx = "AND ("
     For i = 1 To UBound(arrExclude, 1)
        sqlEx = sqlEx & sep & "[4] NOT LIKE '%" & _
                arrExclude(i, 1) & "%'" & vbLf
        sep = " AND "
     Next i
     sqlEx = sqlEx & ")"
     strSQL = strSQL & sqlEx
     
     Debug.Print strSQL
```